# How to optimize Code for Wolfram Challenges?

Tags: performance-tuning, memory, algorithm, challenge-community

I am wondering if anyone who has knowledge of optimizing programs in the Wolfram language has any advice on how to optimize the following quantities of programs written to solve [Wolfram Challenges](https://challenges.wolfram.com/).
I realize some of the following categories to optimize may be dependent on the field the challenge is in, such as algorithms, digits, geography, geometry, math puzzles, primes, real-world data, sequences, and strings:
Here are the goals after I submit a working solution I aim to optimize:

- speed score and processing time: Big O runtime and time complexity of the program.
- memory efficiency and space complexity of the program.
- code characters and minimizing the number of characters typed and functions called.
- code bytes
- code leaves

Comment: This question is far too broad in its current state, unfortunately. You will want to focus it down on a specific problem. More generally, I am not sure that "code golf" aims like the last three in your list would even be on topic here.

Comment: I want to optimize some of my submissions but Wolfram Challenges doesn't let you download or view your winning submissions so I need to reprogram a solution to the problems I've solved that I want to optimize.

Comment: I have contacted Wolfram Challenges twice, and both times received no response. I suggested that you be able to download your code that passed the test later on for reference because it is hard to keep track of the automatically generated file name with numbers and letters for later reference. I think it would be helpful if instead of using a hash function to automatically name your file something really hard to remember, name it after the challenge itself.